# FireFox Session Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, uploadify

I am working on a website, in which users can upload file/photos and for uploading i am using uploadify control
I am adding loggedin userID and Current day and year to the file then saving it,I've save the userID in  a Session(Session["userid"]), its working  fine on IE and chrome but when i run it from firefox, it is showing  Session["userid"]= null and because of this its not uploading the file, below is  my code to uploading file

```
public string UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
        {
            try
            {
                if (fileData != null && fileData.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var root = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Uploads\File\";
                    var filname = fileData.FileName.Split('.')[0] + "_" + Session["userid"].ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Day + DateTime.Now.Year + "." + fileData.FileName.Split('.')[1];
                    var path = root + Path.GetFileName(filname);

                    //if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                    //    return "Upload Failed! A file with this name already exists.";                      

                    fileData.SaveAs(path);

                    return "1";
                }
                return "file not selected.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {           
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Although the user is loggedin but still its showing the session null

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have cookies disabled in your firefox

Comment: Session is available in all other code in FireFox, only in this particular code i am not getting session